# Hamiltonian cycle

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonian-path

Assume $A_k$ be an undirected graph with $2^k$ vertices, $\forall k > 1$,$ k \in Z^+$. We use k-digit binary bit strings to
label the vertices of $A_k$, where the labels of adjacent vertices differ by exactly one digit. Prove that $A_k$
has a Hamiltonian cycle $\forall k > 1$, $k \in Z^+$.

Comment: Hint: the dictionary ordering!

Comment: I don't think your criterion is ever achieved. Let's say you have vertex $i$ adjacent to vertex $j$. If the adjacency vectors are $v_i$ and $v_j$, then $v_i[j]=1$ and $v_i[i]=0$, but both of these values change for $v_j$. Here $a[k]$ is the $k$th entry in n-tuple $a$

Comment: I think it must be achieved because this question is from my lecture book.

Comment: It might help to note the graph you are talking about is the cube graph(I know it as Q_n).

Comment: Why has this question been labeled as off topic? It seems fine to me.

Comment: Better question: why isn't this marked as a duplicate. I answered [this question already](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1596142/hamiltonian-cycle-in-a-graph-with-vertices-with-binary-labels) today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SKETCH: You can prove it by induction on $k$. The base case is trivial. For the induction step, start at vertex

$$\underbrace{00\ldots00}_{k+1}$$

and trace out a Hamiltonian path in the subgraph whose labels end in $0$, stopping one step short of a cycle, shift the last bit to a $1$, trace out the corresponding path in reverse, and shift the last bit back to $0$; if you done it right, you’re back at the starting vertex. E.g., for the ordinary cube you have $000,010,110,100,101,111,011,001,000$.